# tidytext: Issue with unnest_tokens and token = 'ngrams'

Tags: r, token, whatsapp, tidytext, unnest

I'm running the following code

```
library(rwhatsapp)
library(tidytext)

chat <- rwa_read(x = c(
  "31/1/15 04:10:59 - Menganito: Was it good?",
  "31/1/15 14:10:59 - Fulanito: Yes, it was"
))

chat %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  unnest_tokens(output = bigram, input = text, token = "ngrams", n = 2)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in unnest_tokens.data.frame(., output = bigram, input = text, token = "ngrams",  : 
  If collapse = TRUE (such as for unnesting by sentence or paragraph), unnest_tokens needs all input columns to be atomic vectors (not lists)
```

I tried doing some research on Google but couldn't find an answer. Column `text` is a character vector so I don't understand why I'm getting an error saying it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because there are some `list` columns that are `NULL`

```
str(chat)
#tibble [2 × 6] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
# $ time      : POSIXct[1:2], format: "2015-01-31 04:10:59" "2015-01-31 14:10:59"
# $ author    : Factor w/ 2 levels "Fulanito","Menganito": 2 1
# $ text      : chr [1:2] "Was it good?" "Yes, it was"
# $ source    : chr [1:2] "text input" "text input"
# $ emoji     :List of 2   ###
#  ..$ : NULL
#  ..$ : NULL
# $ emoji_name:List of 2    ###
#  ..$ : NULL
#  ..$ : NULL
```

we can remove it and it works now

```
library(rwhatsapp)
library(tidytext)
chat %>% 
   select_if(~ !is.list(.)) %>%
   unnest_tokens(output = bigram, input = text, token = "ngrams", n = 2)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#  time                author    source     bigram 
#  <dttm>              <fct>     <chr>      <chr>  
#1 2015-01-31 04:10:59 Menganito text input was it 
#2 2015-01-31 04:10:59 Menganito text input it good
#3 2015-01-31 14:10:59 Fulanito  text input yes it 
#4 2015-01-31 14:10:59 Fulanito  text input it was
```

---

Also, by default `collapse=TRUE`, and this creates an issue when there are `NULL` elements because the lengths gets different when it is `collapse`d.  One option is to specify `collapse = FALSE`

```
chat %>% 
   unnest_tokens(output = bigram, input = text, token = "ngrams",
        n = 2, collapse= FALSE)
# A tibble: 4 x 6
#  time                author    source     emoji  emoji_name bigram 
#  <dttm>              <fct>     <chr>      <list> <list>     <chr>  
#1 2015-01-31 04:10:59 Menganito text input <NULL> <NULL>     was it 
#2 2015-01-31 04:10:59 Menganito text input <NULL> <NULL>     it good
#3 2015-01-31 14:10:59 Fulanito  text input <NULL> <NULL>     yes it 
#4 2015-01-31 14:10:59 Fulanito  text input <NULL> <NULL>     it was
```